# Angularjs: How to intercept errors in external url $resource or $http service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I have a service available on a server distinct from my grunt server, which serves my angularjs app.
The external server is an Apache server, serving JSON data with PHP.
I would like to intercept any possible server error (from "server down", to "404"...).

I have tried to use interceptors, this way:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://www.remote.server.com/api/WRONGPATH',
});

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

  ...

  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function($q) {
    return function(promise) {
      return promise.then(function(successResponse) {
        if (successResponse.config.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET') {
          console.info('success');
        }
        return successResponse;
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        switch (errorResponse.status) {
          case 401:
            console.info('wrong usename or password');
            break;
          case 403:
            console.info('no rights to do this');
            break;
          case 500:
            console.info('server internal error: ' + errorResponse.data);
            break;
          default:
            console.info('error ' + errorResponse.status + ': ' + errorResponse.data);
        }
        return $q.reject(errorResponse);
      });
    };
  });

});
```

with no success: I always fall in the 'default' switch case, with `errorResponse.status == 0`.
I suppose this happens because the browsers stop when intercepting a CORS error...
Everything works just fine if I change the remote url with a local one...

**Is there any possibility to handle angular.js $resource (or $http) remote requests errors?**

*I would also accept a design shift suggestion, like reimplementing my PHP service in a grunt-like way... (my PHP service - actually - just prints a JSON list of image names from a server folder...).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're pushing your interceptor to the wrong place. The [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) indicate that you should be pushing onto:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors
```

rather than:

```
// I can only find references to this on old tutorials, so maybe it's been deprecated
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors
```

So you'd have something like:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
    'response': function(response) {
      if (successResponse.config.method.toUpperCase() !== 'GET') {
        console.info('success');
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    'responseError': function(response) {
       switch (response.status) {
        case 401:
          console.info('wrong usename or password');
          break;
        case 403:
          console.info('no rights to do this');
          break;
        case 500:
          console.info('server internal error: ' + response.data);
          break;
        default:
          console.info('error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.data);
      }

      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  };
});
```

working plnkr: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y42BOA0Q3Pi1GzCX3JPU)

Comment: Thanks, but the only thifference this way is that I intercept *all* responses, even the good (200's) ones, instead of only *error* responses... However, even adding a 404 case, it doesn't intercept 404 errors...

Comment: Well, using responseInterceptors above would intercept _all_ responses  as well. I'm just proposing you use the format angular suggests. You filter through them with your existing switch statement. Could you put together a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) maybe?

Comment: I've made a plnkr using your original code, it just works: http://plnkr.co/edit/y42BOA0Q3Pi1GzCX3JPU

Comment: Thanks! Could it be extended to $resource, instead of ng-click ?

Comment: The interceptors work for all http based operations, which is why this works in my example plnkr. It's not bound to ng-click, ng-click is just used to call a method on the controller's scope, which in turn uses the resource created in the factory.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the "correct" format according to angular's docs, along with the updated plnkr

Comment: Sorry for the late answering... I did just try your plkr, but I do not see any `console.info('error', ...)`. I only see *browser*'s 404, which is exactly my problem... :-)

Comment: sorry looks like I didn't save the plunkr before my last edit, there was a "errorResponse" variable in there that should have just been "response". I updated the plnkr link above. You'll see a browser GET error, but right below it you'll see: "error 404: Not Found", which is the console.log

Comment: Great! Thanks! I was giving up with it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this is an issue relating to CSRF/XSRF protection, rather than AngularJS. You will get the same issue in other frameworks or poj. In PHP you will need to enable CORS if you are accessing your content across domain and will need to specify the servers that require access or open it up.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled
http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Essentially AngularJS is constrained to the response provided by the browser, which is in turn constraining the response since the request is unauthorised due to XSRF protection. Also, regarding AngularJS and XSRF, it will read the token session cookie (provided by the server) and place it into the HTTP header in subsequent requests, which then is up to the server to decide whether or not it will accept it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks. I do enable CORS access in my PHP pages (`<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>` ...), but the problem is I want to intercept errors like server down, or 404, which of course do not even involve the scripting code...