# Calling service from app.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an `$httpProvider` interceptor, like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628907/angularjs-how-to-intercept-errors-in-external-url-resource-or-http-service):

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {

            var _status,
                _message;

            switch (response.status) {
                case 403:
                    _status = 'warning';
                    _message = 'no rights to do this';
                    break;
                case 500:
                    _status = 'danger';
                    _message = 'internal server error';
                    break;
            }


            Alert.add({status: _status, msg: _message});

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

`Alert` is a service I've reated to display notifications, errors etc. It depends on `$rootScope` and simply adds an object to be rendered in html.

So the question is: how do I call my `Alert` service from `app.config` where this interceptor is defined? Or, if it's not possible, how can I catch all http errors in one place and display them?

Comment: What do you mean by _call my Alert service from app.config_? Do you want to configure it? And what about _ how can I catch all http errors in one place and display them_? Isn't that what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: Well, to display an error I'd like to use a service Alert. And this code obviously doesn't work, cause I can't call a service from the interceptor

Comment: Have you tried `function ($q, AlertService)`?

Comment: Wow, stupid me. That works!

Comment: @zeroflagL I think `function ($q, AlertService)` won't work..

Comment: @pankajparkar Obviously is does. Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: because I faced that issue earlier, my be because angular registers interceptor on cofig block. at that time no service would be availabe..expect the angular common API

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$injector` and then inside the interceptor you could get the service by doing `$injector.get` any service name.

**Code**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $injector) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {
            var service = $injector.get('myService'); //here you can get service
            var _status,
                _message;

            switch (response.status) {
                case 403:
                    _status = 'warning';
                    _message = 'no rights to do this';
                    break;
                case 500:
                    _status = 'danger';
                    _message = 'internal server error';
                    break;
            }


            Alert.add({status: _status, msg: _message});

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

**Update**

As per @zeroflagL solution It would work in simpler way by only dependency injection of service directly in function.

**Code**

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, myService) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {
            var _status,
                _message;

            switch (response.status) {
                case 403:
                    _status = 'warning';
                    _message = 'no rights to do this';
                    break;
                case 500:
                    _status = 'danger';
                    _message = 'internal server error';
                    break;
            }


            Alert.add({status: _status, msg: _message});

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @k102 I don't think so that solution would work..could you confirm it please?

Comment: His solution works exactly the way I wanted and now I'm using it. So, if that comment will become an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: @k102 I updated the answer.kindly look at it..but the way suggested by zeroflagL will not work for `$modal` service..I don't know why? I faced the same problem in previous day..